# Regex for pulling video ID from Rumble URL

Tags: php, regex

Argh-- regular expressions make me crazy, I've just spent 20 minutes trying to get this to fly and I'm having no luck. And I know someone here will be able to pop this out in like 2 seconds! :-)

Here's a sample source URL: `https://rumble.com/v30sqt-oreo-ice-cream-cake.html`

I want to extract the "**v30sqt**" characters. Actually, I want to extract any characters after "rumble.com/" and before the first dash. It might be alphanumeric, it might be all letters, it might be longer than 6 characters, etc. That's the video ID.

This is for php `preg_match`.

Comment: Regex `~rumble\.com/([^-]+)-~`? https://regex101.com/r/rE2mZ9/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one should work for you :

```
/(?<=rumble.com\/).*?\b/g
```

[Demo and Explaination](https://regex101.com/r/fT4pL0/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead of using `regex` along with [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function like as

```
$url = "https://rumble.com/v30sqt-oreo-ice-cream-cake.html";
$parsed_arr = explode("-",ltrim(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH),"/"));
echo current($parsed_arr);
```

or

```
echo $parsed_arr[0];
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://3v4l.org/r8WCH)

Answer (score 0):

Go for:

```
<?php

$url = "https://rumble.com/v30sqt-oreo-ice-cream-cake.html";
$regex = '~rumble\.com/(?P<video>[^-]+)~';

if (preg_match($regex, $url, $match)) {
    echo $match['video'];
    # v30sqt
}
?>
```

With [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/j43Tmp).